# Strange results in Holt forecast

Tags: r, forecasting, seasonality, exponential-smoothing

I am trying to understand what could be causing these strange values to appear on applying a Holt model to a vector. The data represents actual sales of an item.

```
library(forecast)

sdata<-c(1955651,1691857,1617358,1509591,1452025,1387790,1630114,3522984,3322908,2315689,
4044634,11553435,9747305,5289976,3905946,1646080,1356731,1248135,1150756,848804,847815,
940673,1129751)

> holt(sdata)
Point Forecast         Lo 80         Hi 80          Lo 95         Hi 95
24  6.144027e+122 6.144014e+122 6.144041e+122  6.144007e+122 6.144048e+122
25  6.144033e+122 4.502199e+122 7.785866e+122  3.633064e+122 8.655001e+122
26  6.144038e+122 3.822133e+122 8.465942e+122  2.592991e+122 9.695084e+122
27  6.144043e+122 3.300300e+122 8.987785e+122  1.794914e+122 1.049317e+123
```

This involves an exercise where a very large number of forecasts has to be generated. This is merely an attempt to find errors before the forecast is run across all the data. A number of records generated such strange records. I am sure there is a good explanation behind why we see such data.

Note that the data was coerced to a ts object prior to the model being applied on the same (and produced similar results)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a new bug. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prof. Hyndman is as an expert on this. But if you change the method used for selecting initial state values (i.e. `initial` argument) to "simple" then it works well as follows:

```
> library(forecast)
> sdata<-c(1955651,1691857,1617358,1509591,1452025,1387790,1630114,3522984,3322908,2315689,
+ 4044634,11553435,9747305,5289976,3905946,1646080,1356731,1248135,1150756,848804,847815,
+ 940673,1129751)
> f=holt(sdata,initial=c("simple"))
> f
   Point Forecast    Lo 80   Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
24         865957 -1748445 3480359  -3132425  4864339
25         602163 -3095159 4299485  -5052404  6256730
26         338369 -4189908 4866646  -6587032  7263770
27          74575 -5154228 5303378  -7922190  8071340
28        -189219 -6035199 5656761  -9129874  8751436
29        -453013 -6856963 5950937 -10247010  9340984
30        -716807 -7633864 6200250 -11295532  9861918
31        -980601 -8375246 6414044 -12289734 10328532
32       -1244395 -9087600 6598810 -13239542 10750752
33       -1508189 -9775653 6759275 -14152184 11135806
> plot(f)
```

[image]

Comment: Even better, use ets(sdata, model="AAN") which is equivalent to Holt's method.